# NAND read returns 0 blocks

Tags: integrated-circuit, firmware, nand

I need to perform a firmware extraction, so I extrcted the NAND TSOP48 chip from the board.

[image: extracted NAND]

Chip part no: S34MS01G200TFI00

Link to chip: [link to chip](https://www.worldwayelec.com/pro/spansion/s34ms01g200tfi00/5363779)

I then mounted it on a NAND reader

[image: NAND ProMan programmer]

Link to NAND ProMan programmer: [NAND proman programmer link](https://www.vipprogrammer.com/proman-programmer-for-tsop48-tsop56-nand-flash-and-nand-nor-programmer-3126)

The ProMan software works and shows me the manufacturer and chip id, but it cannot detect the chip parameters.

[image]

It returns the error in the image below.

[image]

What manual parameters should I fill in for this type of NAND?

[image]

Or is it somehow read protected? I don't know what I am doing wrong.

! to note that it is the second chip I have tested. The first one has been mounted on the SMT adapter

[image: SMT NAND]

Comment: I'd say you broke it. Why don't you just get the firmware from the original creator?

Comment: Well, because I cannot find it.. why do you say it's broken? It still recognizes the manufacturer, so it must be working, right? A few more details about what could have gone wrong during this process would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. This is six really big photos with a few lines inbetween, asking for loads of information and explanations in return. Is every single one of those full-size photos essential? They make the actual single question very hard to assimilate. Please edit your question to show your own work, conclusions and own findings in considerable detail. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: Ensure all pins are making correct contact (which you may have done).